# Insert a string 3 characters from the start of a concatenated string

Tags: mysql, set

Is it possible in MySQL to insert a string three characters from the beginning of a concat() w/out using SET and UPDATE?

I have a concatenation like:

```
 REPLACE(CONCAT(c.data1,c.data2), ' ', '') AS full_concat
```

and I need to add a "T" three characters from the start of these results.

Before concat:

```
data1: 330080S
data2: 0380E021
```

Concat looks like:

```
330080S0380E021
```

Should look like:

```
33T0080S0380E021 (note the T 3rd position in).
```

Comment: What do c.data1 and c.data2 contain? Give an example output string as well.

Comment: It's ugly, but you'd have to do more substring operations to extract the first 3 chars and the 'remainder' of the whole derived field, then concat those pieces with the 'T' in the middle. At some point, you'd be better off doing that kind of transformation client-side instead of making your SQL statement uglier and longer.

Comment: @Marc B. Thanks for the input. I'll probably ending up going the client side route.

Comment: do you want to insert `T` at 3rd position only If yes, I think @Madbreaks answered it...

Comment: An old question, OldWest, but would you mind accepting one of the answers below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
REPLACE(
    CONCAT(
        SUBSTR(c.data1,0,2),
        'T',
        SUBSTR(c.data1,2),
        c.data2
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT insert(concat('330080S', '0380E021'), 3, 0, 'T') = '33T0080S0380E021'`

[INSERT(str,pos,len,newstr)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_insert)

Comment: Definitely more charming than this Replace/Substring massacre ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
REPLACE(CONCAT('ttt',c.data1,c.data2), ' ', '') AS full_concat
```

like this?

Comment: Concat looks like:
    
    330080S0380E021

Should look like:

    33T0080S0380E021 (note the T 3rd position in).

Comment: oh.. you need to insert your T in the string. Ok, your 33 prefix is fix for all your records?